# What kind of waves can penetrate walls/floors and cause tingling, headache, nausea, etc?

Tags: high-frequency, wave

What types of waves would be able to penetrate walls and floors and at high frequency or intensity would cause symptoms like tingling or burning skin, headache, nausea, and heart palpitations? I know it sounds strange, but just go with me here.

Comment: Tsunami waves .

Answer (score 4):

[Ionizing radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation). Not sure if it is a "wave" in your definition, you with some effort ionizing radiation can be made to come and go (i.e. in waves). Lethal in large doses.

How well it penetrates your floors and doors depends on what they are made of. Concrete/cement is [pretty good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_protection) at stopping radiation, however, "pretty good" is relative here, and assuming you do not live in bunker/nuclear reactor, your walls/floors are probably relatively porous w.r.t radiation.

Incidentally, many forms of electromagnetic radiation (i.e. waves) can penetrate many types of solid matter: you can listen to your radio or talk on your cellphone in your house, ergo, they penetrate walls/floors). These do not usually, directly cause itching and other symptoms you describe. Radiation in the infra-red spectrum will be felt as heat, but usually cannot penetrate solid matter. The military is working on some [radiation-based weapons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Denial_System) (hat tip to [DavidKessner](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3624/david-kessner) for pointing this out), but these also seem to require line of sight:

> The beam can be focused up to 700 meters away, and is said to
>   penetrate thick clothing although not walls.

and:

> ADS may only work successfully against exposed skin, implying that
>   heavier clothing may reduce its effectiveness.